# Проблема с проектом после открытия в Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Почему-то при открытии проекта он открылся в Xcode 9. После того как ошибка была замечена, проект открыла в Xcode 8. Но при открытии Storyboard элементы не показываются, только некоторые контуры (ещё пишет в ошибках Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed). Подсветка кода и подсказки отпали. Также не запускается на симуляторе/устройстве, только по Cmd-B пишет Build Successful.

Cmd-Shift-K не помогает, Cmd-Alt-Shift-K тоже. В проекте в настройках Xcode3.2-compatible. Можно ли что-то сделать? Откатитываться к прошлому коммиту не хочется - довольно много изменений.

Comment: Попробуйте закрыть XCODE и почистить кэш приложений, мне помогло (например simpleCleaner)

Comment: @Fabio Force quit Xcode и очистка Кеша частично помогла - появились симуляторы, проект собирается и запускается. Но в сториборде по-прежнему только контуры